# Is there a way for an XmlListModel not to display items for which a XmlRole is empty?

Tags: xml, qt, qml

I would like to use the following XmlListModel

```
XmlListModel {
    xml: "<feed>"
         +"  <entry><title>Bob</title></entry>"
         +"  <entry><title></title></entry>"
         +"</feed>"

    query: "/feed/entry"

    XmlRole { name: "title"; query: "title/string()" }
}
```

and not to display entries with an empty title.

Of course, the XML comes from a remote source that I don't own.

I have found no information about such a possibility.

Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `query` property of `XmlListModel` is using XPath, you can do some filtering here.

Having `query: "/feed/entry[title != '']"` will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

[`XmlListModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-xmllistmodel-xmllistmodel.html) only has the task of obtaining the items from an XML, so filtering must be a different process. For that case you can use a [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html)(C++) or use [`DelegateModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html)(QML), in this case I will show the second method:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.14
import QtQml.Models 2.14

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 300
    visible: true
    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: delegateModel
    }
    DelegateModel {
        id: delegateModel
        model: xmlmodel
        delegate: Text {
            id: name
            text: qsTr("title: ") + title
        }
        items.onChanged: update()
        groups: DelegateModelGroup {
            id: visibleItems
            name: "visible"
            includeByDefault: false
        }
        filterOnGroup: "visible"
        function update() {
            if (items.count > 0)
                items.setGroups(0, items.count, "items");
            var visible = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < items.count; ++i) {
                var item = items.get(i);
                // filter items
                if (item.model.title !== "") {
                    visible.push(item);
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < visible.length; ++i) {
                item = visible[i];
                item.inVisible = true;
                if (item.visibleIndex !== i)
                    visibleItems.move(item.visibleIndex, i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    XmlListModel {
        id: xmlmodel
        xml: "<feed>"
             +"  <entry><title>Bob</title></entry>"
             +"  <entry><title></title></entry>"
             +"</feed>"

        query: "/feed/entry"
        XmlRole { name: "title"; query: "title/string()" }
    }
}
```